# What's the best way to have a collection of instances of classes all derived from the same base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, collections, smart-pointers

I have a collection of classes all derived from a common base. I need a collection (probably a `list`) that will hold instances of derived classes of various types. Class operations will call virtual methods on the instances in the collection. Of course, I can't use `list<Base>` because holding the base class by value will slice the derived classes.

The obvious solution is to use `list<Base*>` and wrap it in a class with a copy constructor, a destructor, and so on. The base class would have a virtual `duplicate` function that is overloaded in each derived class to return a pointer to a copy-constructed new instance of that derived class. The destructor has to traverse the list and `delete` each item.

If there's a Boost way to do this, that's fine. I'm using Boost already. It seems to me that using Boost's shared pointers would be the best way. There would be overhead in managing the shared reference counts, but that's got to be less expensive than the allocate/copy required in the pointer case. However, this will mean that copies of the collection will result in the same instances and changing one copy will change the other.

I don't yet completely know how this code is going to actually be used. So I'm not sure if the shared copy semantics are going to be a problem. I don't think copies are going to be common, they just need to be handled sanely.

Is there another way?

Comment: If objects are not heavy then first try boost pointer containers, else try an STL container (vector, list, etc.) with boost::shared_ptr

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say hello to [Boost.PointerContainer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). By default, these offer deep-copy semantics when you copy the containers (this is, however, customisable). Note that you need to implement a free `new_clone` method for your abstract base class in the appropriate namespace.

Also, as a side note, *please* use `std::vector` as your first-choice container.

Another side note, don't wrap the `container<Base*>`, but rather wrap the `Base*` in, you guessed it, a smart pointer. C++11 offers `unique_ptr` if you don't want shared ownership. `unique_ptr` only allows *moving* it, you can't copy it.

Comment: I should have guessed that Boost has a class that specifically solved this exact problem! With this solution, I'll need a null object type. I'll probably just use the base class for that.

Comment: @David: See also [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9645090/500104) wrt `new_clone`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: you do *not* need a null object type. A `boost::ptr_vector` is specifically designed not to allow null pointers by default, *but* it can be tuned with `nullable`, see [the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#null-values)

Comment: @MatthieuM.:  Thanks! I still think I want a null object type since null objects will be rare and it'd be easier to just call methods on them that know to do the right thing than have to check for null everywhere. But it's nice that I'm doing it because I think it's best, not because I'm forced to do it by the container.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: If it is meaningful for your application, then I agree a null object type can make your life easier.

Comment: I kind of stopped reading your answer at first after I saw the pointer to Boost.PointerContainer. I shouldn't have. Your last two paragraphs are bang on too. Thanks again.